# Click event doesn't work an not error showing up

Tags: ionic-framework, vue.js

I just created an App using Vue JS and Ionic. Always when I'm using click events nothing is happening. The Code is correct. I checked it an also used some code from the documentation and the same problem appears. 
The console is empty and no error is displaying.
Does anyone habe the same problem and knows any solution?

I would be very thankful :)

Best regards!

```
<template>
  <ion-page class="ion-page" main>
    <ion-content class="ion-content" padding>
      <ion-button @click="openModal">Open Modal</ion-button>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  methods: {
    openModal() {
      console.log('test');
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try @click.native ?

Comment: @MatheusValenza Yes, it's still the same problem badly.